# what is up with this "modified 2 hours ago by Community" questions in the "active" list

Tags: support

When I check the "active" questions, there are often questions included that are considered "active" because there were "modified N hours ago" and the modifying user is "Community".
If open the question, I don't see any edit N hours ago, in fact most of the time the last activity was weeks, months or even years ago.

Can anyone please clarify what is going on here?

Personally I find it very inconvenient to see these long-time-inactive questions in the active stream, as sometimes I don't notice it's an old question until after I answer it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question without an accepted answer will be "modified" by the system from time to time so that it pops back up and gets looked at again. It will keep looking for an answer until it has an accepted answer.

This happens on all the SE sites.

Comment: Thanks Ron. Is there also a recurring job that reminds the OP to flag an answer as accepted? :)

Comment: No, just me when I see questions which were answered by the OP. I comment that the answer should be accepted. There are many times the OP doesn't like any real given answer (e.g. you can't do it that way) and refuses to accept an answer, or the OP gets his answer and just goes away, never to return.

Comment: I noticed that you do that, and I appreciate it. Thanks.